# C++ adding an integer to a string without to_string

Tags: c++, string, integer

What I want to do is this:

```
int num = 10;
string message = "something something " + num;
cout<<message<<endl;

the output would be:  something something 10
```

The compiler I'm being forced to use is an outdated version of GCC, and does not have C++ 11 support, which means **to_string will not work.**

Is string stream the only way?  If so, how would I use it in this case to produce the least amount of code?

Comment: just use `cout<<message<<num<<endl;` in this case? And yes, stringstream is probably the easiest general solution, others exist tho.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl this isn't an exact example.  In reality, I want to return message to a caller function, however string stream seems to be the way to go.

Comment: `boost::lexical_cast` will do this almost just as easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own `to_string`:

```
template <typename T>
inline std::string to_string(const T& t)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << t;
    return oss.str();
}
```